# Getting the same results using different similarities in Lucene

Tags: java, lucene, information-retrieval

We're using Lucene in Java to search for documents and find out if they're relevant or not. We're searching in 6 different ways:

- VSM Similarity with Porter stemmer and stop words
- VSM Similarity with Porter stemmer and no stop words
- VSM Similarity with standard stemmer and stop words
- BM25 Similarity with Porter stemmer and stop words
- BM25 Similarity with Porter stemmer and no stop words
- BM25 Similarity with standard stemmer and stop words

Results from search configuration 3 and 6 are the same, and the results from configuration 1, 2, 4 and 5 are also the same. This indicates that only changing the analyzer (the stemmer) alters anything.

We've tried debugging it to check if the objects are what we expect them to be, but everything seems to be in order - just the objects behaving differently than we hope. We are also remembering to use the same similarity when indexing and searching.

What are we doing wrong? Are we missing some code to 'apply' the configuration properly?

```
    public IndexWriterConfig index(List<DocumentInCollection> docs) throws IOException 
    {

        Analyzer analyz;
        IndexWriterConfig config;

        if (analyzer.equals("vsm") && stopwords && stemmer) 
        {
            //VSM cosine similarity with TFIDF + stopwords + stemmer
            CharArraySet stopWords = EnglishAnalyzer.getDefaultStopSet();
            analyz = new EnglishAnalyzer(stopWords);
            config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyz);
            config.setSimilarity(new ClassicSimilarity());
        } 
        else if (analyzer.equals("vsm") && !stopwords && stemmer) 
        {
            //VSM cosine similarity with TFIDF - stopwords + stemmer
            analyz = new EnglishAnalyzer(CharArraySet.EMPTY_SET);
            config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyz);
            config.setSimilarity(new ClassicSimilarity());
        } 
        else if (analyzer.equals("vsm") && stopwords && !stemmer) 
        {
            //VSM cosine similarity with TFIDF - stopwords - stemmer
            CharArraySet stopWords = StandardAnalyzer.STOP_WORDS_SET;
            analyz = new StandardAnalyzer(stopWords);
            config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyz);
            config.setSimilarity(new ClassicSimilarity());
        } 
        else if (analyzer.equals("bm25") && stopwords && stemmer) 
        {
            //Analyzer + stopwords + stemmer
            CharArraySet stopWords = EnglishAnalyzer.getDefaultStopSet();
            analyz = new EnglishAnalyzer(stopWords);
            config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyz);
            //BM25 ranking method
            config.setSimilarity(new BM25Similarity());
        } 
        else if (analyzer.equals("bm25") && !stopwords && stemmer) 
        {
            //Analyzer - stopwords + stemmer
            analyz = new EnglishAnalyzer(CharArraySet.EMPTY_SET);
            config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyz);
            //BM25 ranking method
            config.setSimilarity(new BM25Similarity());
        } 
        else if (analyzer.equals("bm25") && stopwords && !stemmer) 
        {
            //Analyzer + stopwords - stemmer
            CharArraySet stopWords = StandardAnalyzer.STOP_WORDS_SET;
            analyz = new StandardAnalyzer(stopWords);
            config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyz);
            //BM25 ranking method
            config.setSimilarity(new BM25Similarity());
        }
        else 
        {
            //some default
            analyz = new StandardAnalyzer();
            config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyz);
            config.setSimilarity(new ClassicSimilarity());
        }


        IndexWriter w = new IndexWriter(corpus, config);

        //total 153 documents with group 5
        for (DocumentInCollection doc1 : docs) {
            if (doc1.getSearchTaskNumber() == 5) {
                Document doc = new Document();
                doc.add(new TextField("title", doc1.getTitle(), Field.Store.YES));
                doc.add(new TextField("abstract_text", doc1.getAbstractText(), Field.Store.YES));
                doc.add(new TextField("relevance", Boolean.toString(doc1.isRelevant()), Field.Store.YES));
                w.addDocument(doc);
                totalDocs++;
                if (doc1.isRelevant()) relevantDocs++;
            }
        }

        w.close();

        return config;
    }

    public List<String> search(String searchQuery, IndexWriterConfig cf) throws IOException {

        printQuery(searchQuery);

        List<String> results = new LinkedList<String>();


        //Constructing QueryParser to stem search query
        QueryParser qp = new QueryParser("abstract_text", cf.getAnalyzer());
        Query stemmedQuery = null;
        try {
            stemmedQuery = qp.parse(searchQuery);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        // opening directory for search
        IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(corpus);
        // implementing search over IndexReader
        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

        searcher.setSimilarity(cf.getSimilarity());

        // finding top totalDocs documents qualifying the search
        TopDocs docs = searcher.search(stemmedQuery, totalDocs);

        // representing array of hits from TopDocs
        ScoreDoc[] scored = docs.scoreDocs;

        // adding matched doc titles to results
        for (ScoreDoc aDoc : scored) {
            Document d = searcher.doc(aDoc.doc);
            retrieved++;
            //relevance and score are printed out for debug purposes
            if (d.get("relevance").equals("true")) {
                relevantRetrieved++;
                results.add("+ " + d.get("title") + " | relevant: " + d.get("relevance") + " | score: " + aDoc.score);
            } else {
                results.add("- " + d.get("title") + " | relevant: " + d.get("relevance") + " | score: " + aDoc.score);
            }

        }


        return results;
    }
```

Comment: how could I compare only 2 strings ? I want to know what is their similarity, based on one type of analyser... do you know how to do this ?

Comment: If you didn't find a solution already, open a question about this. I have only used Lucene in this one case and totally forgot it even existed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you wouldn't usually expect BM25 and Classic Similarities to return a different set of results, just different scores (and thus ordering).  Generally, the similarity governs how scores are calculated for documents that have already been found to match the query.  They will typically return the same results, but with different scores, and so in a different order.

If you are seeing the same *scores* with the bm25 and vsm settings, then yes, something is going wrong.  However, your code *looks* okay to me, based on my trimmed down, runnable test version:  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/baf279806702edb54fab23db6d8d19b9

The StopWord filter really often isn't that big a change.  It governs whether stop words are indexed.  Stop words are words like "the" and "this".  With the stop word filter they aren't indexed, and can't be searched.  Unless you are searching for a stop word, the difference generally won't really be obvious.  Again, this *seems* to be working correctly based on my test version.

Comment: I like your answer and if I may add , the evaluation of such systems should be done with metrics such as precision at position or MAP over the whole data set and not just with accuracy check.

Comment: should the similarity be affected by the number of docs in the docs list ? Turns out that your code this happens... I don't know why...